# Odoo: javascript. Can't access some view constructs

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I don't get whats going on here, but I can't access some of Odoo views. Particulary, I need to access `gantt` view.

So running this

```
odoo.define('mymodule.myWidgetName', function (require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var data_manager = require('web.data_manager');

console.log('list ' + core.view_registry.get('list'));
console.log('calendar ' + core.view_registry.get('calendar'));
console.log('diagram ' + core.view_registry.get('diagram'));
console.log('form ' + core.view_registry.get('form'));
console.log('graph ' + core.view_registry.get('graph'));
console.log('grid ' + core.view_registry.get('grid'));
console.log('kanban ' + core.view_registry.get('kanban'));
console.log('gantt ' + core.view_registry.get('gantt'));
console.log('tree' + core.view_registry.get('tree'));
console.log('many2many_kanban ' + core.view_registry.get('many2many_kanban'));
console.log('one2many_kanban '+ core.view_registry.get('one2many_kanban'));
console.log('pivot ' + core.view_registry.get('pivot'));

});
```

Log output is this:

```
list function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}
this._super=null;if(!initializing&&this.init){var ret=this.init.apply(this,arguments);if(ret){return ret;}}
return this;}

web.assets_backend.js:3126 calendar undefined

web.assets_backend.js:3126 diagram undefined

web.assets_backend.js:3126 form function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}
this._super=null;if(!initializing&&this.init){var ret=this.init.apply(this,arguments);if(ret){return ret;}}
return this;}

web.assets_backend.js:3126 graph function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}
this._super=null;if(!initializing&&this.init){var ret=this.init.apply(this,arguments);if(ret){return ret;}}
return this;}

web.assets_backend.js:3126 grid function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}
this._super=null;if(!initializing&&this.init){var ret=this.init.apply(this,arguments);if(ret){return ret;}}
return this;}

web.assets_backend.js:3126 kanban undefined

web.assets_backend.js:3126 gantt undefined

web.assets_backend.js:3126 tree function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}
this._super=null;if(!initializing&&this.init){var ret=this.init.apply(this,arguments);if(ret){return ret;}}
return this;}

web.assets_backend.js:3126 many2many_kanban undefined

web.assets_backend.js:3126 one2many_kanban undefined

web.assets_backend.js:3126 pivot function Class(){if(this.constructor!==OdooClass){throw new Error("You can only instanciate objects with the 'new' operator");}
this._super=null;if(!initializing&&this.init){var ret=this.init.apply(this,arguments);if(ret){return ret;}}
return this;}
```

AS you can see from log, views like `gantt` or `kanban` are undefined. Though if I log `console.log(core.view_registry.map))`. I can see that every one of them have values of their constructs - I mean it looks like every view is defined..

So `core.view.registry.map` log outputs this:

As you can see some views are undefined even though I see that they were registered there and should be accessible. if I `console.log(core.view_registry.map)` 
It returns this:

```
calendar: function Class()
diagram: function Class()
form: function Class()
gantt: function Class()
graph: function Class()
grid: function Class()
kanban: function Class()
list: function Class()
many2many_kanban: function Class()
one2many_kanban: function Class()
pivot: function Class()
tree: function Class()
```

As you can see every key has its construct. So how come some are undefined?..

So what the heck is going on here?? Am I missing some gotcha here?

If dependencies are important in this case, my module is dependent on both `web` and `web_gantt` (which defines `gantt` view, though I guess only `web_gantt` should be needed as dependency anyway).

Also Looking into how `gantt` view is defined:

```
core.view_registry.add('gantt', GanttView);
return GanttView;
```

It looks like it should be straightforward and I should be able to access `GanttView`, but for some reason I can't..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to directly access `gantt` view without going into `view_registry` using `var GanttView = require('web_gantt.GanttView')`. Though it still does not make sense to register view into registry if it can't be access from there.